# deep linking running fine on debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, cross-platform

> **when I am running this code in debug, deep linking is working perfectly but in release mode it's showing error in terminal. It's opening the app but not the specific page in the app. Currently I am clicking the '/page/sehat-scan linking'.................................................................?
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grxMr.png)**

> ```
> class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
>   final Function()? onAppBarLeadingPressed;
>
>   const BottomNavBar({
>     Key? key,
>     required this.onAppBarLeadingPressed,
>   }) : super(key: key);
>
>   @override
>   State<BottomNavBar> createState() => BottomNavBarState();
> }
>
> class BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar>
>     with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
>       // deep link method
>   **_handleDeepLinks() async {
>     final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
>     await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
>
>     if (initialLink != null) {
>       final Uri deepLink = initialLink.link;
>       print('Deeplinks uri:${deepLink.path}');
>       if (deepLink.path == '/doctor-now') {
>         pageController.jumpToPage(
>           2,
>         );
>         _bottomNavCubit.updateIndex(3);
>         pageController.page ==3;
>         currentIndex = 3;
>       }
>    // this link i am clicking right now
>       else if (deepLink.path == '/page/sehat-a-z') {
>         pageController.jumpToPage(
>           1,
>         );
>         _bottomNavCubit.updateIndex(1);
>         pageController.page ==1;
>         currentIndex = 1;
>       }
>
>       else if (deepLink.path == '/doctors/karachi') {
>         NavigationUtil.push(
>             context,
>             RouteConstants
>                 .instantConsultationIntroRoute12);
>       }
>
>
>       else if (deepLink.path == '/page/sehat-scan') {
>         pageController.jumpToPage(
>           2,
>         );
>         _bottomNavCubit.updateIndex(2);
>         pageController.page ==2;
>         currentIndex = 2;
>
>       }
>       else if (deepLink.path == '/wellness') {
>         NavigationUtil.push(
>             context,
>             RouteConstants
>                 .wellnessRoute);
>       }
>     }
>   }**
>
>   PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0);
>   late BottomNavCubit _bottomNavCubit;
>   var _familyMembersList = <FamilyMember>[];
>   late BinahCubit _binahCubit;
>   List<String> _scanTypesList = [];
>   final _battery = Battery();
>   late FamilyMember _myFamilyMemberData;
>
>   late HealthCheckHistoryCubit hmhCubit;
>
>   UserModel? _user;
>   List<HealthScans> myHealthScansHistoryList = [];
>   List<HealthScans> familyHealthScansHistoryList = [];
>   bool scansDataLoaded = false;
>   bool isSuccess = false;
>
>   late FamilyMembersCubit familyMembersCubit;
>
>   bool _cameraPermissionEnabled = false;
>
>   int currentIndex = 0;
>
>   Future<void> getAllData() async {
>     scansDataLoaded = true;
>     setState(() {});
>     _user = _appCubit.user;
>     final userName = _user?.name;
>     if (_appCubit.isLoggedIn) {
>       _myFamilyMemberData = FamilyMember.fromJson(
>         _user?.toJson(),
>       )..updateName = '$userName (Me)';
>    
>       scansDataLoaded = true;
>     } else {
>       isSuccess = true;
>       _familyMembersList.add(FamilyMember(name: 'Guest'));
>     }
>     setState(() {});
>   }
>
>   Future<void> _getToken(SplashCubit splashCubit_) async {
>     await splashCubit_.getToken(
>       platform: Platform.isIOS
>           ? AppConstants.iosPlatform
>           : AppConstants.androidPlatform,
>       appVersion: AppConstants.appVersion,
>       screen: TokenScreenTypeEnum.bottomNav,
>     );
>   }
>
>   void _setScanTypeData() {
>     _scanTypesList = [];
>     if (_binahCubit.defaultSessionType == SessionType.face) {
>       _scanTypesList.add(StringConstants.face);
>       if (_scanTypesList.contains(StringConstants.face)) {
>         _scanTypesList.add(StringConstants.finger);
>       }
>     } else if (_binahCubit.defaultSessionType == SessionType.finger) {
>       _scanTypesList.add(StringConstants.finger);
>       if (_scanTypesList.contains(StringConstants.finger)) {
>         _scanTypesList.add(StringConstants.face);
>       }
>     }
>   }
>
>   @override
>   void initState() {
>     pageController.addListener(() {
>       currentIndex = pageController.page!.toInt();
>     });
>     _appCubit = BlocProvider.of<AppCubit>(context);
>     _binahCubit = BlocProvider.of<BinahCubit>(context);
>     hmhCubit = BlocProvider.of<HealthCheckHistoryCubit>(context);
>     familyMembersCubit = BlocProvider.of<FamilyMembersCubit>(context);
>
>     _user = _appCubit.user;
>     _appCubit.isLoggedIn
>         ? WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async {
>       await BlocProvider.of<HomeCubit>(context).getSettings();
>       await getAllData();
>       setState(() {});
>     })
>         : null;
>     _bottomNavCubit = BlocProvider.of<BottomNavCubit>(context);
>     pageController = PageController(
>       initialPage: _bottomNavCubit.getBottomNavIndex,
>     );
>     _setScanTypeData();
>     WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
>       FirebaseMessagingService.onFirebaseNotificationTapWhenAppIsKill();
>     });
>     super.initState();
>     _handleDeepLinks();
>   }
>
>   void _onPageChanged(int index, {bool updatedCubit = false}) {
>     pageController.jumpToPage(
>       index,
>     );
>     if (updatedCubit) {
>       _bottomNavCubit.updateIndex(index);
>     }
>     currentIndex = index;
>     setState(() {});
>   }
>
>   Widget _bottomNavItem({
>     required String label,
>     String? svgPath,
>     required int index,
>     required bool isVideo,
>   }) {
>     return GestureDetector(
>       onTap: () => _onPageChanged(
>         index,
>         updatedCubit: true,
>       ),
>       child: Stack(
>         alignment: Alignment.center,
>         children: [
>           Container(
>             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
>               bottom: 6,
>             ),
>             color: ColorConstants.transparent,
>             child: Column(
>               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
>               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
>               children: [
>                 if (svgPath == null)
>                   const Icon(null)
>                 else
>                   SizedBox(
>                     child: index == 2
>                         ? SvgPicture.asset(
>                       height: 40,
>                       svgPath,
>                       color: index == _bottomNavCubit.getBottomNavIndex
>                           ? ColorConstants.pink
>                           : ColorConstants.grey,
>                     )
>                         : SvgPicture.asset(
>                       height: 20,
>                       svgPath,
>                       color: index == _bottomNavCubit.getBottomNavIndex
>                           ? ColorConstants.pink
>                           : ColorConstants.grey,
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                 SizedBoxConstants.sizedBoxEightH(),
>                 SizedBox(
>                   child: TextComponent(
>                     label,
>                     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
>                     style: FontStylesConstants.subtitleThree(
>                       color: index == _bottomNavCubit.getBottomNavIndex
>                           ? ColorConstants.pink
>                           : ColorConstants.grey,
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                 ),
>                 SizedBoxConstants.sizedBoxEightH()
>               ],
>             ),
>           ),
>           if (isVideo)
>             Positioned(
>               top: 2,
>               right: 4,
>               child: Container(
>                 decoration: boxDecoration(
>                     boxColor: ColorConstants.lightGreen, borderRadius: 4),
>                 child: Text(
>                   'Video',
>                   style: FontStylesConstants.subtitleThree(
>                       color: ColorConstants.white),
>                 ),
>               ),
>             )
>         ],
>       ),
>     );
>   }
>
>   static const snackBarDuration = Duration(seconds: 2);
>
>   DateTime? backButtonPressTime;
>
>   Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
>     final now = DateTime.now();
>     final backButtonHasNotBeenPressedOrSnackBarHasBeenClosed =
>         backButtonPressTime == null ||
>             now.difference(backButtonPressTime!) > snackBarDuration;
>
>     if (backButtonHasNotBeenPressedOrSnackBarHasBeenClosed) {
>       backButtonPressTime = now;
>       ToastComponent(context).showToast(
>         context,
>         StringConstants.tapAgainToClose,
>         makeToastPositionBottom: true,
>       );
>       return false;
>     }
>
>     return closeApp();
>   }
>
>   closeApp() {
>     if (Platform.isAndroid) {
>       SystemNavigator.pop();
>     } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
>       exit(0);
>     }
>   }
>
>   late AppCubit _appCubit;
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     final isUrdu = getIt<AppCubit>().isUrdu(context.locale.toString());
>     return GestureDetector(
>       onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
>       child: BlocConsumer<HomeCubit, HomeState>(
>         listener: (context, state) {
>           if (state is SettingsLoadingState) {
>           } else if (state is SettingsSuccessState) {
>             _appCubit.settings = state.settingsPreferanceWrapper.data!.settings;
>             LoggerUtil.logs('@@ $state');
>           } else if (state is SettingsFailureState) {
>             ToastComponent(context).showToast(context, state.error);
>           }
>         },
>         builder: (context, state) {
>           return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppState>(
>             listener: (context, state) {
>             },
>             builder: (context, state) {
>               return BlocConsumer<UpdateUserCubit, UpdateUserState>(
>                 listener: (context, state) {
>                 },
>                 builder: (context, state) {
>                   return BlocConsumer<SplashCubit, SplashState>(
>                     listener: (context, state) async {
>                       if (state is SplashTokenLoadingBottomNavState) {
>                       } else if (state is SplashTokenSuccessBottomNavState) {
>                         await getIt<DioClientNetwork>()
>                             .initializeDioClientNetwork(
>                           token: state.token,
>                           userId: (_appCubit.user?.id ?? 0).toString(),
>                           locale: isUrdu ? 2 : 1,
>                         );
>                         if (!mounted) return;
>                         await BlocProvider.of<BottomNavCubit>(
>                           context,
>                         ).updateIndex(0);
>                         await NavigationUtil.popAllAndPush(
>                           context,
>                           RouteConstants.bottomNavRoute,
>                         );
>                       } else if (state is SplashTokenFailureBottomNavState) {
>                         // LoadingDialog.hide(context);
>                         if (!mounted) return;
>                         ToastComponent(context).showToast(
>                           context,
>                           state.error,
>                         );
>                       }
>                     },
>                     builder: (context, state) {
>                       return BlocConsumer<BottomNavCubit, BottomNavState>(
>                         listener: (context, state) async {
>                           if (state is BottomNavLogoutLoadingState) {
>                             LoggerUtil.logs('###logoutLoading');
>                           } else if (state is BottomNavLogoutSuccessState) {
>                             LoggerUtil.logs('###logoutSuccess');
>                          
>                             _appCubit.user = null;
>                             await getIt<SharedPreferencesUtil>().removeValue(
>                               SharedPreferenceConstants.user,
>                             );
>                             await getIt<SharedPreferencesUtil>().removeValue(
>                               SharedPreferenceConstants.userId,
>                             );
>                  
>                             if (!mounted) return;
>                             await getIt<DioClientNetwork>()
>                                 .initializeDioClientNetwork(
>                               deleteToken: true,
>                               locale: isUrdu ? 2 : 1,
>                             );
>                             await _getToken(
>                               BlocProvider.of<SplashCubit>(context),
>                             );
>                             if (!mounted) return;
>                             ToastComponent(context).showToast(
>                               context,
>                               state.message,
>                             );
>                           } else if (state is BottomNavLogoutFailureState) {
>                             LoggerUtil.logs('###logoutFailure');
>                             ToastComponent(context).showToast(
>                               context,
>                               state.error,
>                             );
>                           } else if (state is BottomNavIndexUpdated) {
>                             _onPageChanged(state.index);
>                           } else if (state
>                           is BottomNavDeleteAccountLoadingState) {
>                             LoggerUtil.logs('###deleteLoading');
>                           } else if (state
>                           is BottomNavDeleteAccountSuccessState) {
>                             LoggerUtil.logs('###DeleteAccountSuccess');
>                            
>                             _appCubit.user = null;
>                             await getIt<SharedPreferencesUtil>().removeValue(
>                               SharedPreferenceConstants.user,
>                             );
>                       
>                             if (!mounted) return;
>                             await getIt<DioClientNetwork>()
>                                 .initializeDioClientNetwork(
>                               deleteToken: true,
>                               locale: isUrdu ? 2 : 1,
>                             );
>                             await _getToken(
>                               BlocProvider.of<SplashCubit>(context),
>                             );
>
>                             if (!mounted) return;
>                             ToastComponent(context).showToast(
>                               context,
>                               state.message,
>                             );
>                           } else if (state
>                           is BottomNavDeleteAccountFailureState) {
>                             LoggerUtil.logs('###DeleteAccountFailure');
>                             ToastComponent(context).showToast(
>                               context,
>                               state.error,
>                             );
>                           }
>                         },
>                         builder: (context, state) {
>                           return WillPopScope(
>                             onWillPop: onWillPop,
>                             child: MainScaffold(
>                               extendBody: true,
>                               bottomNavigationBar: _bottomAppBar(),
>                               appBar: AppBarComponent(
>                                 onLeadingPressed: widget.onAppBarLeadingPressed,
>                                 leadingImagePath: _appCubit.user?.image ?? '',
>                                 titleImage: AssetConstants.appBarTitleSvg,
>                                 trailingWidget: Row(
>                                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
>                                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
>                                   children: [
>                                     if (_appCubit.isLoggedIn)
>                                       Container(
>                                         padding:
>                                         const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
>                                         child: GestureDetector(
>                                           onTap: () {
>                                             final NotificationArgs args =
>                                             NotificationArgs(
>                                               userImage:
>                                               _appCubit.user?.image ?? '',
>                                               onAppBarLeadingPressed:
>                                               widget.onAppBarLeadingPressed,
>                                               userId: _appCubit.user?.id
>                                                   .toString() ??
>                                                   '21',
>                                             );
>                                             NavigationUtil.push(
>                                               context,
>                                               RouteConstants.notificationRoute,
>                                               args: args,
>                                             );
>                                           },
>                                           child: Image.asset(
>                                             width: 18.0,
>                                             color: const Color(0xff545554),
>                                             AssetConstants.noti,
>                                           ),
>                                         ),
>                                       ),
>                                     SizedBoxConstants.sizedBoxTwelveW(),
>
>                                     appStartScan(
>                                       hmhCubit: hmhCubit,
>                                       appCubit: _appCubit,
>                                       component:
>                                       Padding(
>                                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
>                                           bottom: 0.0,
>                                         ),
>                                         child: SvgPicture.asset(
>                                           "assets/vector/start_scan.svg",
>                                           width: 70,
>                                         ),
>                                       ),
>                                     ),
>                                   ],
>                                 ),
>
>                                 showBottomLine: true,
>                               ),
>
>                               widget: Stack(
>                                 alignment: BlocProvider.of<AppCubit>(context)
>                                     .isUrdu(
>                                     context.locale.toString()) ==
>                                     true
>                                     ? Alignment.bottomLeft
>                                     : Alignment.bottomRight,
>                                 children: [
>                                   PageView(
>                                     controller: pageController,
>                                     physics:
>                                     const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
>                                     children: const [
>                                   
>
>                                       HomeScreen(),
>                                       SehatAtoZCompleteScreen(),
>                                       HealthCheckHomeScreen(),
>                                       InstantConsultationIntroScreen(),
>
>                                       SearchBarScreen(),
>                                     ],
>                                   ),
>                                 ],
>                               ),
>                             ),
>                           );
>                         },
>                       );
>                     },
>                   );
>                 },
>               );
>             },
>           );
>         },
>       ),
>     );
>   }
>
> ///
> ```